# getting ".then() is not a function" error when using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JS:

```
self.obj = {}
self.obj.accessErrors = function(data) {
    var cerrorMessages = [];
    for (prop in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            if (data[prop] != null && data[prop].constructor ==  Object) {
                self.obj.fetch[accessErrors](data[prop]);
            }
            else {
                cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
    return cerrorMessages;
};

self.obj.fetch = {
    X: function() {
        // do stuff.
    },

    Y: function(callback) {
        $http.get('/yposts/').then(
            function(response) {
                self.posts = response.data;
                callback(self.posts);
            },
            function(response) {
                self.posts = {};

                self.obj.accessErrors(response.data).then(function(cerrrorMessages) {
                    callback(posts, cerrorMessages);
                });
            }
        );
    }
};
```

And I am getting an error pointing to this line:

```
self.obj.accessErrors(response.data).then(function(cerrrorMessages) {
```

The error says:

```
TypeError: self.obj.accessErrors(...).then is not a function
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That function doesn't look async, and isn't retuning a promise object.  You will need to use $q.

Comment: `self.obj.accessErrors` returns an array ... an array is not a promise

Comment: In your code, what is actually being called when your code executes this: `self.obj.fetch[accessErrors]`?  Is it an async operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.obj.accessErrors(response.data)` does not return a promise so therefore, you can't use promise methods on it.

If you want it to return a promise and you want that promise to reflect when all the `fetch()` operations are done and those operations are actually async, then you will have to make all your async code into using promises and you will have to combine them all using `Promise.all()` or the angular equivalent and convert from using callbacks in fetch to just using a promise.  Right now, you have a mix which is difficult to program with.

Answer (score 6):

The `.then()` construction is only needed when using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) objects - essentially, instead of returning a value, the function returns an object that *resolves* to a value at some point in the future (which is then passed into the function that you pass to `.then()`.

But you are right in that you need an asynchronous pattern to do this correctly, since `fetch.Y` is an asynchronous method. A good thing to do would be to create an array of promises at the beginning of your `accessErrors` function, like so:

```
var fetchPromises = [];
```

and then replace `self.obj.fetch[accessErrors](data[prop]);` with something that calls `push` on that array to add the promise that `fetch` returns to it.

Then, instead of returning `accessErrors`, return `Promise.all(fetchPromises)`.

This will require some fairly significant modification to your code, however - namely, you will need to rewrite it so that it uses the Promise API instead of this callback by itself (which shouldn't be too difficult to do).